# Unable to set callback function . Error Says: 'DropDown' must have a method body because 'ListLayout' isn't abstract

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a drop down class and a list view. I want to change the state of list view when the drop down item is changed. To do so, i have to setState of list from dropdown class.I learnt about callback function and was trying to implement it. But I got an error.

My Code for drop down class:

```
class DropDown extends StatefulWidget {
final Function _callBack;

DropDown({@required void callBack()}) :
_callBack = callBack;
@override
_DropDownState createState() => _DropDownState();
}
```

Code for ListLayout is here:

```
class ListLayout extends StatefulWidget {
DropDown(dropDownItemChanged );//Error comes here saying 'DropDown' must have a method body 
// because 'ListLayout' isn't abstract.  Try making 'ListLayout' abstract, or adding a body to 
//'DropDown'.

@override
_ListLayoutState createState() => _ListLayoutState();
}

class _ListLayoutState extends State<ListLayout> {

void dropDownItemChanged (String data) {
setState(() {
  ....
    }
  }
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return ....;
}
}
```

I would be grateful if somebody could answer this

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I was not supposed to instantiate DropDown from ListLayout , because DropDown is not a child of ListLayout. May be this helps someone.